# Парсинг mp3 через jsoup в APP

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Всем привет! У меня на сайте есть статьи в которых присутствует mp3 файлы. Как их спарсить? Я так понимаю нужно какой-то плеер подключить в приложение? Подскажите пожалуйста как должно это происходить. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы хотите скачать mp3 файлы? Или хотите в приложении их воспроизвести? Приведите пример сайта с теми статьями

Comment: @gil9red воспроизвести.

Comment: Просто берите стандартный `MediaPlayer` (вроде он так называется) и передавайте в него ссылку на mp3 - почти сразу заиграет.